# how extract 'cancellationDate' this:

Tags: python, json, postgresql, extract, jsonpath

```
["{\"RequestedByUser\":false,\"RequestedBySystem\":null,\"RequestedBySellerNotification\":null,\"RequestedByPaymentNotification\":true,\"Reason\":null,\"CancellationDate\":\"2024-01-16T00:40:59.0928615+00:00\"}"]
```

tryingjson_extract, jsonpath and nothing

Comment: Show your own effort (code) as properly formatted text in the question.

Answer (score 1):

We have a JSON string inside a list. If you want to extract values from this JSON string, you can use the json module in Python.

Try like this

```py
import json

# Your input data
data = ["{\"RequestedByUser\":false,\"RequestedBySystem\":null,\"RequestedBySellerNotification\":null,\"RequestedByPaymentNotification\":true,\"Reason\":null,\"CancellationDate\":\"2024-01-16T00:40:59.0928615+00:00\"}"]

# Assuming there is only one element in the list, you can access it using data[0]
json_data = json.loads(data[0])
cancellation_date = json_data["CancellationDate"]
print("CancellationDate:", cancellation_date)
```

Output:

```
CancellationDate: 2024-01-16T00:40:59.0928615+00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you get a list of Json strings, from that you want to get the CancellationDate. You can do this in python, by loading the json string in the json module. Like this example:

```
import json

json_string_list = ["{\"RequestedByUser\":false,\"RequestedBySystem\":null,\"RequestedBySellerNotification\":null,\"RequestedByPaymentNotification\":true,\"Reason\":null,\"CancellationDate\":\"2024-01-16T00:40:59.0928615+00:00\"}"]
new_json_list = []

for json_string in json_string_list:
    try:
        json_dict = json.loads(json_string)
    except JSONDecodeError:
        continue
    new_json_list.append(json_dict)

if new_json_list:
    print(new_json_list[0]["CancellationDate"])
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't clarify what exactly it is that you're showing. If that's what's in the database, the outer square brackets `[` would mean that your value is a single-element `json` or `jsonb` array. A simpler example would be this:

```
["abcd\",\"efgh"]
```

The middle quotes are escaped with `\`, making the whole thing between the brackets one long string with quotes *in it*.
If that's the case, you'll need to check if that's what you intended to save there.

You can still get that element, treat it as a `json` and ask for your target key in it.

```sql
select ((your_json_column->>0)::json)->>'CancellationDate' from your_table;
```

If you're getting that after fetching the value from the db to your app, it could be your client mapping PostgreSQL's `json`/`jsonb` to Python `string` type and giving you an array of that, as a result list to iterate over. That's mapping a single row resulting from a SQL query to a Python array/list with one element. In that case, instead of pulling the whole thing, you can get your value out of the json right in the db:

```
select your_json_column->>'CancellationDate' from your_table;
```

That way you don't have to read, transfer, map the whole thing from db to Python, then take one thing out - you only get what you wanted in the first place. If there are multiple rows, you'll get an array of just the cancellation dates.

[Demo at db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/w9iakPtg)